# Automatic export database tables from mariadb server to a linux server with .csv file format

Tags: mysql, csv, cmd, mariadb, export-to-excel

I have to automatically generate a csv file of database tables from mariadb server to a linux server. Using maraidb 10.2.33

I created an event in mariadb but I could not find any files generated in the linux server.

my code:

```
 CREATE EVENT `automatic_export_computers` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY_HOUR STARTS '2022-01-24 15:15:00' 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE 
ENABLE 
COMMENT 'Save Table to CSV for Excel' 
Do SELECT * FROM `glpi`.`glpi_computers` 
INTO OUTFILE '/data_computers2.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

so is there any script using I can generate csv file.

plz help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that the event scheduler is enabled. If not, enable it with `set global_event_scheduler=ON` or add the option to your configuration file.
2. Make sure that the user under which MariaDB is running, has permissions to write to the specified location. In your example writing to `/data_computers2.csv` will require that MariaDB server is running as root  (you can specify `./data_computer2.csv` so the file will be written to the data directory of MariaDB server).
3. Open the error log and check why the event wasn't executed successfully.